# Searching xml files inside jars using GREP

Tags: jar, grep, ubuntu-12.04

I want to search number of abc.xml files inside my main directory . those xml files are inside jars.I' m using ubuntu 12.04 LTS . how to search those xml files inside jars using GREP
.I want to know the amount of the total xml files inside that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, you want to know the number of XML files contained within a .jar file.  If that is right, then the following would achieve the desired:

```
jar tvf <jarfile> | grep "\.xml$" | wc -l
```

Assuming that you want to search  within all the jar files in the current directory (and subdirectories), the following should do the trick:

```
total=0;
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.jar"`; do
  count=$(jar tvf $i | grep "abc.xml" | wc -l);
  let total+=count;
done
echo ${total}
```

For simply listing the matching jar files:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.jar"`; do
  jar tvf $i | grep "abc.xml";
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo $i; fi;
done
```

Comment: no i have a  directory which contains several jars  . some of jars containing a xml called abc .xml . I want the total  number of abc.xml 's contains in that directory.

Comment: Thanks it worked . please help to  get what are the jars containing that xml instead of getting the total xml count